# Prove that $\dfrac{(n^2)!}{(n!)^n}$ is an integer for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, binomial-coefficients, divisibility

Prove that $\dfrac{(n^2)!}{(n!)^n}$ is an integer for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$

I know that there are tools in *Number theory* to proves the required but I want to use the tool that says that if you can prove that an expression solves a combinatorial problem then it represents an integer for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$

My solution is, assume we are given $n^2$ beads, $n$ beads in every color of $n$ colors, and we want to place them in a row ($(n^2)!$)
now since we have $n$ groups of colors and every group has $n$ beads in it, we need to cancel the inner sort of each of the groups, which gives us $(n!)^n$ for all the possible inner sorts of the beads.

Will that proof work? What are its flaws?

Comment: Your argument is correct. In slightly more generality, the _multinomial coefficient_ 
$$\displaystyle \binom{n_1+n_2+\cdots n_k}{n_1,n_2, \cdots, n_k}
= \frac{(n_1+n_2+\cdots n_k)!}{n_1!n_2!\cdots n_k!}$$
counts the number of permutations of a multiset with $k$ different
elements occurring with multiplicities $n_i, 1 \leq i \leq k$,
and your problem is the special case when $k = n$ and all the $n_i$ equal $n$.
This is exactly what the accepted answer is saying but without using the
name multinomial coefficient which is sometimes useful to know.

Comment: This is quite an improvement on the fact we usually see, $\frac {(n^2)!}{2^nn!}$ is an integer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Note that $\dfrac{(a+b)!}{a! b!}$ is an integer. In general,
$$\dfrac{\left(\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^m a_k \right)!}{\displaystyle \prod_{k=1}^m a_k!}$$ is an integer. The above can be shown to be an integer by a combinatorial argument. Consider $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^m a_k$ balls, where $a_l$ balls are of color '$l$'. Then the number of possible arrangements of these balls in a straight line is given by $\dfrac{\left(\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^m a_k \right)!}{\displaystyle \prod_{k=1}^m a_k!}$, which is an integer.

In your case, take $m=n$ and $a_k = n$, $\forall k \in \{1,2,\ldots,n\}$.

Comment: Which means in other words that my combinatorial proof is O.K, right? :)

Comment: @Georgey Yes. ${}{}$

Answer (score 7):

The argument can be continued to give an additional $n!$ of divisibility.

After removing the redundancy of the inner ordering within the groups, the groups can be sorted relative to each other (by least element, or in any other way that gives a unique order).

Hence $\frac{(n^2)!}{(n!)^{n+1}}$ is an integer, equal to the number of partitions of $n^2$ different objects into $n$ sets of $n$.

Comment: And you can't increase that $n+1$ to $n+2$ because that fails for $n=2$.

Comment: Or any prime $n$.  But when $n$ is square or a perfect power I think there may be additional factors.  @martycohen

Answer (score 5):

Your proof seems to work.

To add a little formalism, you can prove that $n$ copies of the symmetric group $S_n$ is a subgroup of $S_{n^2}$ by considering $n$ disjoint supports of size $n$. Then Lagrange's theorem concludes the proof. Essentially, this is the same proof as yours.

Answer (score 5):

The product of $n$ consecutive integers is divisible by $n!$, therefore, the product of $kn$ consecutive integers (in particular when $k=n$) is divisible by $(n!)^k$. In particular:

$\dfrac{(n^2)!}{(n!)^n}=\dbinom n n\dbinom{2n}n\dbinom{3n}n\dots\dbinom{n^2}n=\dbinom{n^2}{n,n,n,\dots,n}$.