# A number-theoretic proof that $(n^2)!/(n!)^{n+1}$ is an integer

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, factorial

I have seen a number of combinatorial proofs for this statement. For instance,

[Quotient of factorials](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3160201/quotient-of-factorials?noredirect=1)

However, I am wondering whether there is a purely number-theoretic proof.

Comment: Consider each prime $p \le n$ and show it appears at least as often in the numerator as in the denominator

Comment: I thought about using Legendre's formula, but could not prove the resulting inequality. Could you give the details? Thanks.

Comment: Try an example, such as $n=10$ and $p=3$ and then see if you can generalise

Comment: There are several similar posts, e.g., [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/426454/prove-that-dfracn2nn-is-an-integer-for-every-n-in-mathbbn), and one can always see that a combinatorial solution is more natural than a purely number-theoretical one.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove that $\dfrac{(n^2)!}{(n!)^n}$ is an integer for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/426454/prove-that-dfracn2nn-is-an-integer-for-every-n-in-mathbbn)

Comment: I understand the combinatorial solution, but I think a number theoretic one may shed light on other problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here’s such a proof: note that $(n^2)!=n^n n! \prod_{k=0}^{n-1}{\left[\prod_{l=kn+1}^{kn+(n-1)}{l}\right]}$.

Thus $\frac{(n^2)!}{n!^{n+1}}=\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}{\binom{kn+(n-1)}{n-1}}$ is an integer.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a guide on solving the problem but I yet been able to prove it with rigorous.

We can probably prove by letting $p_k$ be the $k$th prime.
We can let
$n!=p_1^{a_1}p_2^{a_2}\cdots$ and $(n^2)!=p_1^{b_1}p_2^{b_2}\cdots$
We can notice that:
$a_i=\sum_{s=1}^{\infty}\lfloor\frac{n}{p_i^s}\rfloor$
$b_i=\sum_{s=1}^{\infty}\lfloor\frac{n^2}{p_i^s}\rfloor$
Hence, we only have to prove
$b_i\ge(n+1)a_i$ for all $i$ such that $p_i\le n$ as it is trivial for any $p_i>n$ to not be present in the denominator.
$\Rightarrow \sum_{s=1}^{\infty}\lfloor\frac{n^2}{p_i^s}\rfloor\ge(n+1)\sum_{s=1}^{\infty}\lfloor\frac{n}{p_i^s}\rfloor$
If we are able to prove $\lfloor\frac{n^2}{p_i^s}\rfloor\ge(n+1)\lfloor\frac{n}{p_i^s}\rfloor$, then it shall hold.
I am unable to prove it yet but it can be seen easily by using cases or solved graphically.

Comment: I think the difficulty lies in proving the last inequality, which is not so trivial. That is probably why this question is interesting.